# How to install Perl Switch.pm module required to build WebKit-GTK?

Tags: 12.10, perl, webkit, cpan

I noticed that the perl version (5.14) shipped with 12.10 does not include the Switch.pm module needed while building WebKiT-GTK.

Looking around on the internet I found few suggestions indicating that I should install something call p5-switch from ports. I have looked around and was not able to get this done. I am not a perl guy and have no idea where i can get this package.

Can someone please help me as to

1. Where to download the package for ubuntu 12.10
2. In case it is not a .deb, How do i install it.

Comment: Do you have libswitch-perl installed?  It's normally shipped with all of the images.  There's also a version in perl-modules.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to install the [Switch.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Switch-2.16/Switch.pm) Perl module into your system Perl config, there are two methods of installing it:

1. Install it through the Ubuntu repositories.
2. Install the .pm through [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/).

At this time, both will provide the current version of this module(2.16).

**Installing Switch.pm using the Ubuntu repositories:**

- From the command-line, the installation can be completed by running the following command from the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>):

  `sudo apt-get install libswitch-perl`

  - Within Synaptic, right-click on the `libswitch-perl` package, select Mark for installation, then click on the Apply button.
  - Within the Ubuntu Software Center (USC), search for the phrase `libswitch-perl`, highlight the package and select install:

**Installing Switch.pm using CPAN:**
If you would prefer to install this via cpan, follow these instructions:

1. Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>).
2. Enter the command `cpan`.
3. At the prompt `cpan[1]>`, type `install Switch`.
4. Once completed, Type `exit`.

The Switch.pm Perl module will now be available for you to use in your scripts.